# Visual Studio Code - unverified breakpoint while debugging nodejs code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Following is the environment :

VS Code Version : 1.25.0
Node js : v6.11.1

Whenever i try to put the break point within a method it shows "unverified break point" and don't get hit while debugging the code. This has started happening very recently. Not sure what is the reason for this. Any help in this regard shall be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Yes , Actually i installed a npm named "Istanbull" for the purpose of code coverage and due to that the debugging was not working. For now i have commented that plugin and finding the solution to make both the things working at the same time.